React Native 0.72.15 Android - library "libandroidicu.so" not found
I'm in the process of upgrading our React Native project from 0.71.15 to 0.72.15.
The app works fine for the most part but I'm getting a crash straight to the home screen when I try to run a certain feature in the app. React Native doesn't log any errors but I saw the following error in Flipper:
dlopen: dlopen failed: library "libandroidicu.so" not found: needed by /system/lib64/libharfbuzz_ng.so in namespace (default)
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7c4d9b5fc0 in tid 10871 (mqt_js), pid 10753

I've tried updating the ndk version as recommended in another thread but the crash still occurs.
Our build.gradle looks like this:
    ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = project.hasProperty('minSdkVersion') ? project.getProperty('minSdkVersion') : 23
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
    bitriseNdkPath = "/usr/local/share/android-sdk/ndk-bundle"
    kotlin_version = "1.7.22"
    kotlinVersion = "$kotlin_version"
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    classpath("io.sentry:sentry-android-gradle-plugin:4.2.0")
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
      url("$rootDir/../node_modules/detox/Detox-android")
    }
}
}
}

Any help or insight on this would be greatly appreciated.
